# Как имитировать ввод в консоль python

Tags: python

Код:

```
import time
from threading import *
def one():
    print(input())
def two():
    time.sleep(1)
    #здесь имитируем ввод в консоль что б функция one смогла принять значения
t1 = Thread(target=one)
t2 = Thread(target=two)
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Для чего мне это надо: в библиотеке telethon есть добавление сессии и там надо ввести код с самого телеграма(я хочу это немного автоматизировать что б каждый раз не лезть на хостинг)

Comment: надо подменить sys.stdin.

нужен пайп os.pipe() или терминал os.openpty(). С пайпом у меня не получилось - попробуй терминал. А ещё простой вариант - это положить всё добро в subprocess.

Самый простой способ тут - это пропатчить саму прогу

Comment: Один из вполне рабочих вариантов использование библиотеки pyautogui,здесь  подробно о его использовании https://medium.com/nuances-of-programming/%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%81-python-a4c9f210a064